Improper content script management when given broad permissions with Safari Extension (converted from Chrome)
Everything works perfectly in Chrome and kinda works in Safari but starts to produce a bug whenever you give broad permissions (access to all websites) in Safari.
I've got a couple of content scripts for different domains/paths and one default one (for unsupported urls).
Whenever I give "access to all websites" the whole thing just bugs out and acts quite weirdly - content script A can be loaded into website C, even though the matches are entirely different (it will never happen in Chrome). It seems to be a very solid bug.
If I don't give broad permissions and just give access to "website A" - it seems to work fine. But it's not possible to just leave it like this since users will never do it this way.
I saw someone encountered this bug, but there was no solution. Trying my luck to see if anyone figured out what the issue and solution is. Thanks.

If Safari supports optional_host_permissions and browser.permissions.request + browser.scripting.registerContentScripts, use them instead of content_scripts.
